# What is the likelihood of asbestos in this plaster?

Tags: plaster, asbestos

The plaster in the following images is from 1958.

What is the likelihood of it containing asbestos?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lab-test, I can confirm that the plaster does **not** contain asbestos. I have been told by craftsmen that the probability of plaster containing asbestos in Denmark is almost non-existing.

Answer (score 2):

if its from the 50's the chances are very high. however, it is region specific often.  if you are located in the eastern us or canada, there is a very good chance of it.  if you are worried about it, you can remove a small sample and take it to a local health lab or college chemistry lab and have it tested.

Comment: It's located in Denmark. The danish asbestos info-sites **almost** never mentions plaster as a risk - only insulation, roofcoverings etc.

Comment: sorry -  i know nothing of danish plaster or danish asbestos.  my expertise is exclusively north american.  the lab approach is still the easiest way to know for sure.  good luck

Comment: Whatever you do, don't sand or grind it without taking proper precautions.